# Speeding up numeric integral

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, manipulate, numerics

How can I speed up the following integral? It takes a lot of time to evaluate!

```
\[Omega] = 1064*10^(-9);
es[e1_, w2_, \[Delta]x_, \[Delta]y_, x_, y_] = 
  e1*Exp[-((x - \[Delta]x)^2 + (y - \[Delta]y)^2)/w2^2]*
   Exp[I*\[Omega]*t];
el1[e2_, wl2_, x_, y_, t_, \[Beta]_, \[CapitalOmega]_] = 
  e2*Exp[-(x^2 + y^2)/wl2^2]*Exp[I*\[Beta]*Sin[\[CapitalOmega]*t]]*
   Exp[I*\[Omega]*t];

sum1[e1_Real, w2_Real, \[Delta]x_Real, \[Delta]y_Real, e2_Real, 
   wl2_Real, t_Real, r_Real, \[Beta]_Real, \[CapitalOmega]_Real] := 
  NIntegrate[(Abs[
      es[e1, w2, \[Delta]x, \[Delta]y, x, y] + 
       el1[e2, wl2, x, y, t, \[Beta], \[CapitalOmega]]])^2, {x, 0, 
    r}, {y, -(r^2 - x^2)^0.5, (r^2 - x^2)^0.5}];
```

Also, in this program, I would like to use the Manipulate[ ] function to change the values of various parameters, and inspect the behavior of sum1. Is there a way to do this faster?

Answer (score 2):

Another approach is to simplify the integral by hand.  We start by defining our two functions
$$E_S = E_1 e^{-\frac{(x-\delta x)^2+(y-\delta y)^2}{W^2}}e^{i\omega t}$$
$$E_L = E_2 e^{-\frac{x^2+y^2}{L^2}}
e^{i\beta\sin(\Omega t)}e^{i\omega t} \;.$$
We add these functions, take the magnitude squared, and expand that as the product of the sum and its complex conjugate
$$|{E_S+E_L}|^2=\overline{(E_S+E_L)}(E_S+E_L) \;.$$
To evalue this product, we introduce expressions $f_1$, $f_2$ and $f_3$ as
$$f_1=\overline{E_S} E_S=E_1^2 e^{-2\frac{(x-\delta x)^2+(y-\delta y)^2}{W^2}}$$
$$f_2=\overline{E_S} E_L+ E_S\overline{E_L}=2E_1E_2 e^{-\frac{(x-\delta x)^2+(y-\delta y)^2}{W^2}} e^{-\frac{x^2+y^2}{L^2}}\cos(\beta \sin(\Omega t))$$
$$f_3=\overline{E_L} E_L=E_2^2 e^{-2\frac{x^2+y^2}{L^2}}$$

Now we want the integral of $f_1+f_2+f_3$, which we can get numerically by specifying values for $\delta x$, $\delta y$, $r$, $W$ and $L$ (note that my use of $W$ and $L$ instead of the symbols in the original post).

```
g1[δx_, δy_, r_, W_] := 
 e1^2  NIntegrate[
   Exp[-2 ((x - δx)^2 + (y - δy)^2)/W^2], {x, 0, 
    r}, {y, -(r^2 - x^2)^(1/2), (r^2 - x^2)^(1/2)}]

g2[δx_, δy_, r_, W_, L_] := 
 2 e1 e2 NIntegrate[
   Exp[-((x - δx)^2 + (y - δy)^2)/W^2] Exp[-(x^2 + y^2)/
      L^2], {x, 0, 
    r}, {y, -(r^2 - x^2)^(1/2), (r^2 - x^2)^(1/
       2)}] Cos[β Sin[Ω t]]

g3[r_, L_] := 
 e2^2 NIntegrate[
   Exp[-2 (x^2 + y^2)/L^2], {x, 0, 
    r}, {y, -(r^2 - x^2)^(1/2), (r^2 - x^2)^(1/2)}]
```

We can test the integrals with something like

```
With[{δx = 1, δy = 1, r = 5, W = 2, L = 3},
 g1[δx, δy, r, W] + g2[δx, δy, r, W, L] + 
  g3[r, L]
 ]
(*   5.2843 e1^2 + 7.04126 e2^2 + 10.7584 e1 e2 Cos[β Sin[t Ω]]   *)
```

These numerical integrations evaluated quickly.  A second advantage of this approach is that we can more easily see the effect of changing the parameters $E_1$, $E_2$, $\beta$, and $\Omega$.  We also note that $\omega$ does not appear.

Comment: Thank you! This helps.

Answer (score 1):

Do these edits fix or improve it for you?

```
\[Omega] = 1064*10^(-9);
es[e1_, w2_, \[Delta]x_, \[Delta]y_, x_, y_, t_] := 
  e1*Exp[-((x - \[Delta]x)^2 + (y - \[Delta]y)^2)/w2^2]*
   Exp[I*\[Omega]*t];
el1[e2_, wl2_, x_, y_, t_, \[Beta]_, \[CapitalOmega]_] := 
  e2*Exp[-(x^2 + y^2)/wl2^2]*Exp[I*\[Beta]*Sin[\[CapitalOmega]*t]]*
   Exp[I*\[Omega]*t];

sum1[e1_?NumericQ, 
   w2_?NumericQ, \[Delta]x_?NumericQ, \[Delta]y_?NumericQ, 
   e2_?NumericQ, wl2_?NumericQ, t_?NumericQ, 
   r_?NumericQ, \[Beta]_?NumericQ, \[CapitalOmega]_?NumericQ] := 
  NIntegrate[(Abs[
      es[e1, w2, \[Delta]x, \[Delta]y, x, y, t] + 
       el1[e2, wl2, x, y, t, \[Beta], \[CapitalOmega]]])^2, {x, 0, 
    r}, {y, -(r^2 - x^2)^0.5, (r^2 - x^2)^0.5}];
```

**CHANGES:**

1. The definitions of `es` and `el1` should be `SetDelayed` (`:=`), not `Set` (`=`), because we want to evaluate the RHS not once, but every time they are called.
2. `t` appears in the RHS of `es`, just like in `el1`, so I added it as an argument.
3. Testing for `Head` `Real` in the inputs to `sum1` is not the idiomatic way to restrict the arguments, because I guess we should accept 1 or `Pi`, no? So the correct way is to test using `NumericQ`.

When I run `sum1[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2]` with these modifications, a number is returned instantly.

If more control of `NIntegrate` is needed, you may specify a limited precision using `PrecisionGoal -> 5` or some such number, because `NIntegrate` usually samples the domain adaptively to reach the sought precision. Also, explicitly turning off symbolic preprocessing of the integrand may speed things up in some cases. You can do that using the `Method` options, such as `Method -> {"GlobalAdaptive", Method -> "GaussKronrodRule", 
  "SymbolicProcessing" -> False}`.

Hope this helps!